# Is there a collection of measurable not necessarily nested but converging sets such that we cannot permute measure and limit

Tags: lebesgue-measure

We know that for $\{E_n\}_{n\geq0}$ Lebesgue measurable sets s.t. $E_0\subset E_1\subset...$ we have $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}E_n=\bigcup\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}E_n$ and $\mu(\lim E_n)=\lim(\mu(E_n))$

Similarily if $E_0\supset E_1\supset...$ and $\mu(E_0)<\infty$ we have $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}E_n=\bigcap\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}E_n$ and $\mu(\lim E_n)=\lim(\mu(E_n))$

But what if we lose the property of nestedness? What would be some interesting examples of collections of sets where we cannot permute limit and Lebesgue measure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example: $E_n=[n,n+1]$

Then $\mu(E_n)=1$ for every $n$ but $\lim_{n\to\infty}E_n=\varnothing$ so that $\mu(\lim_{n\to\infty}E_n)=\mu(\varnothing)=0$.

---

**edit**:

With the lemma of Fatou it can be shown that:$$\mu(\liminf E_n)\leq\liminf\mu(E_n)\tag0$$

If some $c>0$ and some integer $n_0$ exists such that $n>n_0\implies E_n\subseteq[-c,c]$ then this can also be applied on the sets $[-c,c]-E_n$ leading to: $$\mu(\liminf E_n)\leq\liminf \mu(E_n)\leq\limsup\mu(E_n)\leq\mu(\limsup E_n)<\infty\tag1$$

You are dealing with a convergent sequence of measurable sets iff $\liminf E_n=\limsup E_n$ so in that case $(1)$ implies that: $$\mu(\lim E_n)=\lim \mu( E_n)$$

---

This shows you that it is somehow inevitable to come up with "sets that dissapear to infinity" for an example that you ask for.

Comment: This doesn't look like a collection of *converging* sets.

Comment: Can we really say that $E_n$ converges though? That would  work for a function $\mathbb{1}_{E_n}$ and the integral for sure...

Comment: @DarthGeek We have $\liminf E_n=\limsup E_n=\varnothing$. That means that $\lim E_n$ exists and equals $\varnothing$.

Comment: Ok yes sorry it does converge. But it’s not a very interesting example

Comment: You are right. My bad. Perhaps @OP is looking for an example where the limit of the sets is not empty tho.

Comment: @DarthGeek Well, then the OP can go for $E_n=[0,1]\cup[n,n+1]$.

Comment: @drhab That looks like an excellent example. I wonder if an example can be found where all the sets are subsets of a bounded set. (I suspect one might have to go to $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n > 1$ for that).

Comment: @DarthGeek I just edited on that topic.